# Break from vimdiff on large number of diff files

Tags: linux, git, vim, diff

I am using `vimdiff` as a diff tool for my git repo. Say I have five modified files and I am done with diff after the second file. How can I tell vim to stop opening the rest of the diff? Right now I just keep closing the buffer using `:qa`. I figured there's gotta be a better way to cut through instead of manually closing one buffer at a time.

I checked `vim :help diff.txt` but don't seem to find what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you get prompts when running `git difftool`? You should get something like this:

```
Viewing (2/5): 'foo.bar'
Launch 'vimdiff' [Y/n]:
```

You can interrupt (`^C`) at the prompt to stop viewing any more changes.

If you don't get the prompt, set `difftool.prompt` option (see `git-config(1)`).

Comment: The thing is I don't like to be prompted every time so I turned it off. Is there not a way to do so without a prompt?

Comment: I don't think so. Anyway, it's not a problem with `vim` but rather with `git`, because for every differing file `git` runs a separate `vim` process. So if there is a solution, I would search in `git` documentation.

Comment: Actually, you could also use the options for the `git difftool`: `--prompt` or `-y`/`--no-prompt`: either leave the `difftool.prompt` as it is and use `--prompt` when you expect that many files will be edited — or set `difftool.prompt` to default and use `-y` when you wouldn't want prompts to appear. But I don't think you have any more options besides that.